# Website loads fine in Chrome, but won't load at all in Safari

Tags: ios, network, google-chrome, mobile-safari

I have a local web server running a basic web site.  The problem I'm having is that the page loads fine in Chrome, however in Safari it wont load at all.

I've tried routing all my traffic through a proxy server and when I load the page in Chrome I see the expected result in the proxy logs, but from Safari there isn't a single entry in the logs, so it appears that Safari is not even attempting to load the page.

I've also tried the following to clear up any potential networking issues:

1. Turning off the iPhone, and then back on again
2. Setting the phone to Airplane mode, and then back on again
3. Reset network settings through the Settings app
4. Removing all cookies/data/history from the Safari settings page

None of the above have resolved the issue.

I'm doing this on an iPhone, latest versions of iOS (and therefore mobile Safari) and the latest Chrome app.

Comment: And you have checked your Safari settings?

Comment: There has been reports that a DNS setting could affect Safari.

Comment: The Safari settings don't mention anything about DNS.  I've tried clearing all website data as well, with no impact.

Comment: DNS settings on your router, not in Safari.